Scraping data Airbnb
I am working on a Python script using Selenium to scrape Airbnb listings from multiple pages and gather information such as the title, price, and details about each listing. The script navigates through pages, extracts links to individual listings, and then visits each link to scrape detailed data. However, I'm encountering issues with correctly capturing all the links and extracting details from each page. Additionally, the script does not throw explicit errors but fails to collect the required data.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import csv
import functools
import datetime

# Initialize WebDriver and navigate to the page
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\WebDriver\bin\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.airbnb.fr/s/Pays-Basque-français--France/homes?...')

# Prepare CSV file for data storage
now = datetime.datetime.now()
filename = f"airBnb_PaysBasque_{now:%Y-%m-%d}.csv"
csv_file = open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='')
writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

# Collect links from multiple pages
house_all_links = []
index = 1
while index <= 17:
    try:
        print(f"Getting list of links from Page {index}")
        links = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//a[@class="atm_9s_1ulexfb "]'))
        )
        house_links = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in links]
        house_all_links.extend(house_links)
        
        next_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//a[@class="l1ovpqvx atm_1he2i46_1k8pnbi_10saat9"]'))
        )
        next_button.click()
        index += 1
        time.sleep(6)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        continue

# Visit each listing and extract details
for url in house_all_links:
    driver.get(url)
    try:
        time.sleep(1.5)
        house_title = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div/span[@class="atm_7l_1kw7nm4 "]'))
        ).text
        price = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="_1jo4hgw"]/span[@class="_1y74zjx"]'))
        ).text
        details = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="atm_c8_km0zk7 "]/ol[@class="atm_gi_idpfg4 "]')
        house_detail = [detail.text for detail in details]
        
        writer.writerow([house_title, price, house_detail])
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

csv_file.close()
driver.close()


Issues:
The script is supposed to scrape links from up to 17 pages but sometimes misses pages or fails to extract some links.
Details such as house_title and price are not consistently extracted.
No explicit errors are shown even when data isn't successfully scraped, making debugging difficult.
Questions:
How can I ensure that all links are reliably captured across all specified pages?
What improvements can I make to reliably extract details from each listing's page?
Are there better approaches to handle dynamic content loading and pagination in Selenium?
I appreciate any help or suggestions on improving this script to handle dynamic content more effectively and ensure data integrity.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Did you use ChatGPT or other AI to come up with this code?

The reason "No explicit errors are shown" is because you've wrapped the entirety of your code in a try-except that is catching Exception type, which is the parent exception type. Get rid of the try-except and then run your script... you'll see all errors so you can investigate and fix them. Once you're all done and the script is running smoothly, then come back and maybe add a try-except back in but only catch the exception types you plan to handle. Eating exceptions hide errors as you've found out the hard way.

@JeffC  In my observations:
The script intermittently skips collecting links from some pages.
There are no explicit error messages, making it difficult to pinpoint the exact cause.
Given this, I believe the XPath selectors used to identify the links and the pagination button might be incorrect or outdated, especially if Airbnb has updated their page structure or class names, which could render my current selectors ineffective.

@BarrythePlatipus No i didn't use it juste i add comment from it

Read my previous comment, follow those instructions, and then come back and report the actual error message.
